# ReactNative, app runs on emulator but not on real iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I am trying to run an app with react native on iOS. The build is correct but when i run it, it shows the splash screen and then stays all white, and xcode throws me this error:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x1dac070fc <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x148
    0x1dac07100 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1dac07104 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1dac0711c               ; <+32>
    0x1dac07108 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1dac0710c <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1dac07110 <+20>: bl     0x1dabfc7d4               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1dac07114 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x1dac07118 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x1dac0711c <+32>: ret
```

(Here on the line with "->" there's an error: `Thread 6: signal SIGABRT`, but it changes on each build)

And:

```
2019-08-23 16:39:38.264 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] `View` has no propType for native prop `RCTView.borderTopEndRadius` of native type `CGFloat`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.
2019-08-23 16:39:38.267586+0200 RFM[321:14377] `View` has no propType for native prop `RCTView.borderTopEndRadius` of native type `CGFloat`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.
2019-08-23 16:39:38.278 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: `View` has no propType for native prop `RCTView.borderTopEndRadius` of native type `CGFloat`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.
2019-08-23 16:39:38.278257+0200 RFM[321:14372] Unhandled JS Exception: `View` has no propType for native prop `RCTView.borderTopEndRadius` of native type `CGFloat`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.
2019-08-23 16:39:38.294345+0200 RFM[321:14372] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: `View` has no propType for native prop `RCTView.borderTopEndRadius` of native type `CGFloat`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: `View` has no propType for native prop `RCTView.borderTopEndRadius` of native type `CGFloat`
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually me..., stack:
verifyPropTypes@26162:22
requireNativeComponent@25498:42
<unknown>@24136:37
loadModuleImplementation@115:12
<unknown>@34748:19
loadModuleImplementation@115:12
<unknown>@34524:24
loadModuleImplementation@115:12
<unknown>@58847:30
loadModuleImplementation@115:12
<unknown>@58500:21
loadModuleImplementation@115:12
<unknown>@58425:23
loadModuleImplementation@115:12
<unknown>@58038:37
loadModuleImplementation@115:12
<unknown>@55269:22
loadModuleImplementation@115:12
<unknown>@1254:19
loadModuleImplementation@115:12
guardedLoadModule@72:45
global code@141506:9
'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1db070ec4 0x1da241a40 0x1016f28c8 0x1016ee6ec 0x1db078630 0x1daf56450 0x1daf57034 0x101706c34 0x101748b80 0x1017488e0 0x101f9b824 0x101f9cdc8 0x101fa4e6c 0x101fa5b60 0x101fafbfc 0x1dac8d0dc 0x1dac8fcec)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I have "react": "16.8.3" and "react-native": "^0.59.9".
I have tried restarting the package, clearing cache, reinstalling, closing/opening the terminal, xcode, etc. as I have seen in some questions like this one, but none has worked.

The thing is that it runs correctly on the emulator, and some coworkers have tried it on the same clean git branch, versions and device and they have no issues. I have also tried with another app we have and it runs correctly on emulator and real device.

Comment: This sounds strange if you got the app run fine on the emulator, and your colleagues go it to run on device with the exact same code.
The only valuable thing I see from the logs is: `Unhandled JS Exception: View has no propType for native prop RCTView.borderTopEndRadius of native type CGFloat
If you haven't changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your versions of the native code and JavaScript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.`
I'd look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I ran `react-native bundle --minify --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios` and it worked...
(Use index.ios.js or index.js)